# Anyone else having troubles deploying react-vite on azure web app?

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, vite, pm2

[image]
I have this MIME type problem with vite, but with Create-React-App everything is fine (on localhost it runs fine )

tried to change vite.config.js
and changed startup command to `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`

Comment: Please share the details of your deployment like how you deployed to the web app. Did you deploy to Linux, and did you make any changes to the code, or did you use the default code before publishing?

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake from my side, instead of pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa I should have pointed to the dist folder, so changing it to pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon --spa  was enough to correct it, i will not delete the post even though it was a stupid mistake from my side, maybe it will help someone

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it was a mistake from my side, instead of

> pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa

I should have pointed to the dist folder, so changing it to

> pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon --spa

was enough to correct it, I will not delete the post even though it was a stupid mistake from my side, maybe it will help someone

Comment: Thank you ! 
remember to restart the machine